# If graph G has 2n+1 vertices where every vertex has degree at least n, G is connected

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

So I need to show that each pair of vertices is joined by a path, or show that there is a vertex joined to every other vertex by a path.

But.. how?

Comment: I think you need to rethink your question. Consider a disconnected graph with 3 components, each is the complete graph $K_5$.

Comment: Oh man that was an absent-minded typo. Thank! I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u,v$ be any two vertices. If they aren't connected directly, then $u$ has at least $n$ neighbours and $v$ has at least $n$ neighbours. If all mentioned vertices were distinct, we would get $2n+2$ vertices. Can you conclude from here?

Comment: Therefore u and v must be neighbours, otherwise we contradict our statement that there are 2t+1 vertices?

Comment: No, the correct conclusion is that they have a common neighbour. From this it follows that they are connected by a path of length 2.

Answer (score -1):

Let $e$ be the number of edges in $G$.Use Handshaking theorem $\sum_1^{2n+1}deg(v)=2e$

$\rightarrow[n(2n+1)/2]\le{e}$..............................................$(1)$

Use the fact that a graph with $n$ vertices that contains more than $(n-1)(n-2)/2$ edges is connected.Replacing $n$ by $2n+1$ in this, we see that $(1)$ holds true, hence $G$ is connected.

Comment: Your fact only holds if the graph has $n$ vertices. This one has $2n+1$.

Comment: You still can't apply this fact.

Comment: Replacing $n$ by $2n+1$ gives $(1)$. Where is the problem?

Comment: Replacing $n$ by $2n+1$ in the fact gives $n(2n-1)$.

Comment: oh! Sorry...my bad..